Does crypto.SE have systems for identifying systematic voting?
There seems to have been another round of negative waves, as:-

Coincidentally it seems that one or several people all voted only once for the above answers, within an hour one day.  And no comments from that time. This has happened a few times before so I guess that this must be a common occurrence across the site.  I know that I write a lot of crap, but notwithstanding, I was under the impression that there were bots in place  specifically looking for targeted down voting.  
Since entropy is a hobby of mine, I realise that this voting pattern could arise by chance. Even several times.  I'm not interested in reviewing those answers, just asking - coincidence/bad answers or no such bot?

First wait 24h to see if the system automatically reverts the votes.

@CodesInChaos Thanks.  Is that a yes - there is such a bot?

Yes, there is such a bot. It works for upvotes too - if you go through a users Q/As and do a voting spree (upvotes or downvotes), they will be rolled back.

Are the only answers being downvoted ones that already have a lot of downvotes, or are well-accepted ones also being randomly downvoted? If even well-received questions are being downvoted, then that's a sign of fraud (or something sketchy for that matter). If only poorly-received answers are being downvoted, then maybe someone's just looking through a bunch of answers and voting as they see fit (which is a legitimate act).

Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it was an answer to your question, and/or to specify how it does not answer your question if it does not.

Quoting our help center:

What if I think I'm the victim of voting abuse?
If you see very unusual votes being targeted at your account, don't
  worry about it. You should wait at least 24 hours after noticing
  before becoming concerned, as the automated system should detect it
  and reverse it for you. If, after 24 hours, you do not see any fix to
  your reputation, please contact the team using the "contact us" form
  located at the bottom of any page.

